# How to connect Azure Cloud from local computer

Tags: azure, mobile-application

I am new to azure, I am doing a mobile application project and I want to connect azure cloud from my local computer. I have created an API and I want to sync data to azure from a local computer. I used visual studio to write the API and I have put the API into the IIS server. It works in the IIS server, I was trying to sync data to Azure cloud. I used ios xcode to write the mobile application I don't know which services should i use in Azure to make it works, it can collect and send data to mobile too.

The service can let me use my own API to sync data to Azure Cloud, it also is able to send and collect data between mobile and Azure Cloud.

Comment: let me know how you deployed the application in azure.

Comment: i used ios swift to write the app

Comment: If you want to deploy an IIS app to Azure, start with the Azure App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview

Comment: but i used ios xcode to write the mobile app, does it works on app services too? and i am using visual studio 2013

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but my web api is connecting to an exisiting sql server database